# Replace list of elements with elements from another list Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, list-comprehension

I have a bit of difficulty explaining exactly what I mean with the title. I want to create a function in Haskell that takes two lists and returns a list of lists where each list is obtained by replacing the ith element from the first list to the ith element from the second list. For example, if given [1,2,3] and [4,5,6] it should return [[4,2,3],[1,5,3],[1,2,6]].
I tried using this recursive function that would return just a list of all the values that I could then break and turn into a list of lists but it loses some elements on the way.

```
replace' :: [a] -> [a] ->[a]
replace' _ [y] = [y]
replace' (x:xs) (y:ys) =  y:xs ++  x: (replace' xs ys)
```

Comment: we can write it for you but the point most probably is for you yourself to enhance your understanding of the situation so that the solution becomes clear. the clearer the question, the easier the solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to the exact solution. There are basically two problems:

1. you want to return a list of lists. The return type is thus `[[a]]`, and the elements of that list are lists, therefore `y:xs` is an *element*, not a sublist; so you use `:` to combine `y:xs` with its tail; and
2. for the rest of the elements, you prepend *all* the sublists with `x`, so that means you perform a `map`ping:

If we fix these two problems, we obtain:

```
replace' :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
replace' [] _ = []
replace' _ [] = []
replace' (x:xs) (y:ys) = (y:xs) : map (x:) (replace' xs ys)
```